# Entity Framework Code First Approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
  public class ContextEx:DbContext 
    {
        public void modelcreate(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ContextEx>(null);
            modelbuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Categories");
            modelbuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(c=> new {c.CategoryID});

            modelbuilder.Entity<CartItem>().ToTable("CartItems");
            modelbuilder.Entity<CartItem>().HasKey(ci=> new {ci.CartId});

            modelbuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Products");
            modelbuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(p=> new {p.ProductID});

            modelbuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable("Orders");
            modelbuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(en=> new { en.OrderId});

            modelbuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>().ToTable("OrderDetails");
            modelbuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>().HasKey(od=> new {od.OrderDetailId });
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categoriesdb { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CartItem> Items { get; set; }

    }

/********************Second Class*****************************/
namespace wing.tip.toys.dal.model
{
    public class Second
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ContextEx cont = new ContextEx();
                List<Category> Category = cont.Categoriesdb.ToList<Category>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here in Line - List Category = cont.Categoriesdb.ToList();
It is throwing me the following exception:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'CartItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Items' is based on type 'CartItem' that has no keys defined.

I'm confused what to do. I have searched everywhere but didn't get the desired solution. Please help me.

Comment: Why `modelbuilder.Entity<CartItem>().HasKey(ci=> new {ci.CartId});` rather than `modelbuilder.Entity<CartItem>().HasKey(ci=> ci.CartId);`?

Comment: I am learning to use Entity Framework and this was what mentioned in the video I was following. It's defining the key variable for the table Cart Item. I also tried doing what you mentioned above but I am still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible problems with your code is that instead of

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelbuilder )
```

you have

```
public void modelcreate(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
```

thus the metadata setup method is never called.

Comment: It worked. Thanks but can you explain me why do we need to use this method and why it has to be protected override?

Comment: You can't name a method with any name and expect the framework to find it and call it. The method already exists in the base class (`DbContext`) and to provide your own implementation, you have to follow the convention (which is - you have to override the method from the base class).